# Android Studio expternalNativeBuild.ndkBuild: Still possible to autogenerate Android.MK?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, java-native-interface, ndk-build

I am currently trying to upgrade my JNI library project to use Android studio 2.2.2

All tutorials say I need to point to my Android.mk, thing is, until now it was autogenerated.

With using `android.useDeprecatedNdk=true` the Android.MK was automatically generated in `projectDir/build/intermediates/ndk/<flavor>/<buildType>/Android.mk`

Now I should point to it in

```
externalNativeBuild {

    // Encapsulates your NDK-Build build configurations.
    ndkBuild {
        path "//path to Android.MK File"
    }
}
```

Does this mean I now have to take care of the Android.MK file myself, or am I missing something?

Before Gradle was generating the Android.MK specifics using blocks like these:

```
ndk {
     cFlags = " -DVENDOR="+vendor+" -DVERSION_NUMBER_MAJOR="+majorVersion+" -DVERSION_NUMBER_MINOR="+minorVersion+" -DVERSION_CODE="+versionCode+" "
}
```

**Update**

The main reason for not using android.useDepricatedNdk=true is that the IDE can't analyze my code. Throws a lot of: Failed to get the compiler information for file...`

The code itself compiles and runs fine actually.

Comment: review the docs and see whether 'cmake' will just handle an import or your code.  https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/index.html

Comment: I don't want to use cmake I want to use ndk-build